# Select all rows if there are id duplicates then select the one (of 2) with particular type

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, amazon-redshift

I have a table
[image: Table]

where some of "job_id"s (the column "job_id") have duplicates. I need to select all columns from that table. If there is a duplicate in the "job_id" column, then select the row with the type (from the column "type") "Pending Starts". I tried also to join the table to itself but it didn't work either.

```
select  *
case x.job_id
    when count(*)>1 then x.type="Pending Starts"
    end as type
from X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a union of two queries. One finds all the rows that don't have a duplicated job ID. The other finds all the duplicated job IDs and returns the rows with `type = 'PendingStarts'`.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM X AS a
JOIN (SELECT job_id
      FROM X
      GROUP BY job_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS b
ON a.job_id = b.job_id

UNION ALL

SELECT a.*
FROM X AS a
JOIN X AS b ON a.job_id = b.job_id
WHERE a.type = 'PendingStarts'
AND b.type != 'Pending Starts'
```

I'm assuming that when there are duplicates, the types are different.

Comment: Thank you! ERROR: 42803: column "X.data_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: You can turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode, or use the updated query in my answer.

Comment: thank you, in the second part I assume you JOIN "ON a.job_id=y.job_id" not b.job_id. But anyways I have this error ERROR: 42601: each UNION query must have the same number of columns

Comment: I meant `JOIN X AS b`. Both queries should have the same number of columns, since `a.*` is the same in both. Maybe you wrote `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT a.*`?

Answer (score 0):

You always want the Pending Starts value, so start with that:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'Pending Starts'
union all
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.job_id = t.job_id and t2.type = 'Pending Starts'
                 );
```

This is not exactly what your question asks for but it appears to be what you might want.